# Using Nokogiri to loop through result pages

Tags: nokogiri

I have some code to extract offers on eBay, but there are several result pages and I get only the results of the first page. How can I loop through several result pages?

Here is my code:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'

    url = "http://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_nkw=Suzuki+DR+BIG&_sacat=131090&_odkw=Suzuki+DR+BIG&_osacat=0&_from=R40"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    doc.css(".dtl").each do |dtl|

       puts dtl.at_css(".vip").text 
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to aggregate the results from each page by pulling the link from the "next" button (which, inspecting the page, is at the css `.botpg-next a`) and loading it.

Something like this:

```
url = "http://www.ebay.de/sch/i.html?_nkw=Suzuki+DR+BIG&_sacat=131090&_odkw=Suzuki+DR+BIG&_osacat=0&_from=R40"
while (url) do
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  doc.css(".dtl").each do |dtl|
    puts dtl.at_css(".vip").text 
  end
  link = doc.css('.botpg-next a')
  url = link && link[0]['href'] #=> url is nil if no link is found on the page
end
```

I'm just looping until no "next" button is found, but you could change that to limit the loop to a given number of results.

Comment: Ok - that does the job perfectly - Thanks a lot. But at the end of my test document I get an error like "open-uri.rb:35:in `initialize': No such file or directory - javascript:; (Errno::ENOENT)
"

Comment: That's because OpenURI is trying to open a URL with a "javascript" scheme, and fails. You'll need to filter for legitimate schemes.